# Information on GSM

Tags: packet, gnuradio

My team and I are using a SDR, GNU Radio, and some other hardware assembled into a custom tablet and a Python program we are writing to detect [IMSI Catchers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IMSI-catcher). I have some Packet Capture files with known IMSI Catcher data I am going through to implement the detection metrics but it has been very difficult to find the data I need about GSM other than very surface data about the protocols like TDMA, CDMA, etc. or completely incomprehensible terrible documentation about the packet structure drawn in ASCII.

**Are there any *good* resources about the GSM protocol and packet contents?**

Most importantly with descriptions of all data fields for all packet types.

---

Some background, one issue that I am trying to solve and can not find documentation for is what packets, and their fields, contain information to build a list of a cells neighbors location area codes (LAC). I have found packets with neighboring cell information:

```
Layer GSM_A.DTAP:
    Measurement Results
    Protocol Discriminator: Radio Resources Management messages (6)
    .... 0110 = Protocol discriminator: Radio Resources Management messages (0x06)
    0000 .... = Skip Indicator: No indication of selected PLMN (0)
    ..11 1111 = RXLEV-FULL-SERVING-CELL: >= -48 dBm (63)
    .... .111  100. .... = BSIC-NCELL: 60
    .... ...0  01.. .... = NO-NCELL-M: 1 neighbour cell measurement result (1)
    RXLEV-SUB-SERVING-CELL: >= -48 dBm (63)
    0001 0... = BCCH-FREQ-NCELL: 2
    0... .... = BA-USED: 0
    .0.. .... = MEAS-VALID: The measurement results are valid
    ..11 1111 = RXLEV-NCELL: 63
    .... 000. = RXQUAL-SUB-SERVING-CELL: BER < 0.2%, Mean value 0.14% (0)
    .000 .... = RXQUAL-FULL-SERVING-CELL: BER < 0.2%, Mean value 0.14% (0)
    .0.. .... = DTX-USED: DTX was not used
    0... .... = 3G-BA-USED: 0
    DTAP Radio Resources Management Message Type: Measurement Report (0x15)
```

But most docs don't even have descriptions of all of the acronyms although I have found most now, and are missing packet types I am trying to examine. There are still about 15 other metrics I need to find also, if there is authoritative documentation on GSM somewhere neither I nor my team have been able to find it.

Comment: not 100% certain this really fits here, according to this nice little [graph](https://ham.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: maybe of interest: https://media.ccc.de/c/osmocon17

Comment: It's a very interesting question, and I would love to see a practical way to detect IMSI-catchers, but I'll be voting to close because I think a question about a radio technology that's not legal for use in amateur radio doesn't belong here.  Good luck.

Comment: The Osmocom material definitely looks useful. I wasn't sure if it was a good fit here. It is legal to passively listen to all GSM traffic without trying to break any encryption. There is a small loophole where the [33-centimeter band](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GSM_frequency_bands#GSM_frequency_bands) overlaps the [European 900 MHz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GSM_frequency_bands#GSM_frequency_bands) and one could run a GSM base station with something like OpenBTS, but we are just passive listening and there could be issues with a legal active implementation, encryption, power level, etc.

Comment: @8bit.wappen but that passive monitoring approach then would be about radio technology that is not amateur technology, again... You don't need to be a ham to legally listen!